# Constant Coefficient Homogeneous 2nd order ODE's with complex roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

ODEs of the form: $a\ddot y + b\dot y + cy = 0$, can be solved through guessing the solution to be: $e^{rx}$ and solving a quadratic equation (yes I know about repeated roots and all, but they're not super relavent to this question). I'm just a little bit confused about expanding these equations when the roots are complex. For example:

$$2\ddot y + y=0 
$$
$$r^2e^{rx} + e^{rx} = 0
$$
$$r^2 + 1 = 0 
$$
The roots to this equation are $\pm \sqrt{-1} = \pm i$, so the full solution is: $e^{\pm ix}$. According to Euler's Formula (of which I am not very familliar with, this is my first time encountering it and also complex numbers properly in mathematics), we can expand this expression.
$$e^{\pm ix} = \text{cos}(\pm x) + i\text{sin}(\pm x) = \text{cos}(x) \pm i\text{sin}(x)
$$
For the general solution, we just take the linear combination:
$$ c_1(\text{cos}(x) + i\text{sin}(x)) + c_2(\text{cos}(x) - i\text{sin}(x))
$$
$$ \text{cos}(x)(c_1 + c_2) + i\text{sin}(x)(c_1 - c_2)
$$
This is probably where I would naturally stop, but in all the explanations I looked at, they omit the $i$ and write each term with the coefficients $A$ and $B$ like this:
$$A\text{cos}(x) + B\text{sin}(x)
$$
I find this very confusing, I mean why $A$ and $B$, I thought we always name the constants $c_n$ or even sometimes $C, D, E, ...$, but I've never seen them written as $A$ and $B$. More importantly, why is the $i$ just dropped, especially with physical phenomena like Hooke's Law, I can't find a single explanation anywhere as to where the imaginary coefficient goes, they always jump to the $A$ and $B$ form. I'm all very new to Differential Equations and I apologize if I've made some obvious mistake, but I can't seem to get my mind off this. Sorry if my question is also poorly worded, thank you for reading, all answers are greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: A constant is a constant no matter what you call it. For why $i$ "drops," it comes from considering $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$ and then solving for sine and cosine, finding appropriate consrants.

Comment: One can find some previous instances of this question like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986847/real-or-complex-numbers-for-the-general-solution, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109817/confused-about-characteristic-equation.